# Input 0 of layer "dense_9" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1

Tags: python

when I try to compile the program I get the following error:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "dense_9" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

I am attaching the program code below:

```
data_array = np.array([2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5])

target_array = np.array([2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4])

array1 = {'data': data_array, 'target': target_array}

class array1:

  data = array1["data"]

  target = array1["target"]

obiect = array1()

X_train, X_vaild, y_train, y_vaild = train_test_split(

    obiect.data, obiect.target)

model = keras.models.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),

])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer="sgd")

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=190,


                    validation_data=(X_vaild, y_vaild))
```

When I provide lists of values ​​in a "data_array" variable, everything works. However, when I provide single values, I get an error.

Comment: even if you have single value you still have to use as `data_array` - as array with single value.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is in the comment by furas. Everything works.